# Laravel livewire expression is not allowed here when using $this

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am building an EditModal using Laravel Livewire with real-time validation.

To achieve validation, I've got to define the `$rules` property like so:

```
 <?php 
 //...
//REAL-TIME VALIDATION (https://devdojo.com/tnylea/snippet/laravel-livewire-real-time-validation)
protected $rules = [
    'name'=>'required|min:4|min:2|max:255',
    'guard_name'=>'required|min:2|max:255',
    'permission'=>'required|min:2|max:255'
    'description'=>'required|min:5|max:255'
];
```

However, When I try to validate unique except the current record, I feel the need to use `$this->record_id`,

```
<?php
//...
    protected $rules = [
        'name'=>'required|min:4|min:2|max:255|unique:permissions,name,'.$this->record_id,
        'guard_name'=>'required|min:2|max:255',
        'permission'=>'required|min:2|max:255|unique:permissions,permission,'.$this->record_id,
        'description'=>'required|min:5|max:255'
    ];
```

but the error I'm facing now is:

> Expression is not allowed as field default value

or

> Constant expression contains invalid operations

Well, it means I can't use `$this` to call the property containing the record ID.

Then how do I work around this? How do I access to the current ID inside the `$rules` property?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Livewire forum](https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/livewire-update-validation-on-unique-field/2930/2), I had to create a protected function like so:

```
<?php
// ...
protected function rules() //https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/livewire-update-validation-on-unique-field/2930/2
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required|min:4|min:2|max:255|unique:permissions,name,'.$this->record_id,
            'guard_name'=>'required|min:2|max:255',
            'permission'=>'required|min:2|max:255|unique:permissions,permission,'.$this->record_id,
            'description'=>'required|min:5|max:255'
        ];
    }
```

Then call it inside my submission method simply like that:

```
<?php
//..
    public function permissionUpdate()
    {
        $this->validate();
        //... update the record
    }
```

And that did the trick